# Odds that the jack of trump dealt 46% of time in pitch

Tags: probability, distributions, games

In the [game of Pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_%28card_game%29) what are the odds of the jack of trump being dealt in the 24 cards?

Comment: Another recent pitch question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11885/odds-for-high-in-the-card-game-pitch

Answer (score 2):

This question almost answers itself. If trumps were chosen randomly, then the answer would be approximately 46%, as it says in the title ($24/52 \simeq 0.46$). However, in reality the trump suit is determined by the first player, and therefore the probability is a function of this player's strategy.